# Permitir edição do input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao selecionar a forma de pagamento, é preenchido o valor da taxa padrão, mas essa taxa devo permitir a edição dela.

Preciso manter a estrutura da minha função, mas ao mesmo tempo permitir que o valor da taxa seja alterado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".moeda").maskMoney({decimal: ",",thousands: "."});

  $('#valorCurso, #formaPagamento, #formaTaxas, #poloComissao').bind('focusout change', function() {

    var formaID = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").val();
    var formaTxt = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").text();
    var formaTaxa = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").attr('data-taxa');
    var formaTipo = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").attr('data-tipo');


    if (formaID == "") {
      var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val("0.00");
    } else {
      var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val(formaTaxa + formaTipo);
    }



  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

Forma de pagamento:
<select id="formaPagamento" name="formaPagamento" required>
  <option value="" selected></option>
  <option value="1" data-taxa="3.50" data-tipo="">Boleto</option>
  <option value="2" data-taxa="3.50" data-tipo="%">Cartão credito</option>
  <option value="3" data-taxa="1.50" data-tipo="%">Cartão debito</option>
  <option value="4" data-taxa="0.00" data-tipo="">Dinheiro</option>
</select>

Taxa: 
<input id="formaTaxas" name="formaTaxas" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="0,00" required/>
```

Comment: Remover o seletor `#formaTaxas` do evento não resolve o problema?

Comment: @VictorCarnaval Não, porque a intenção seria que ao terminar de mudar o valor já recalcularia tudo automaticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie outro *event handler* com o evento `input` apenas para o campo `#formaTaxas`. Ao alterar o valor do campo, irá alterar também o valor do atributo `data-taxa` da option ativa no select:

```
$('#formaTaxas').bind('input', function() {
   $("#formaPagamento option:selected").attr("data-taxa", this.value);
});
```

Veja em funcionamento:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".moeda").maskMoney({decimal: ",",thousands: "."});

   $('#formaTaxas').bind('keyup', function() {
      $("#formaPagamento option:selected").attr("data-taxa", this.value);
   });
   
   $('#valorCurso, #formaPagamento, #formaTaxas, #poloComissao').bind('focusout change', function() {
   
      var formaID = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").val();
      var formaTxt = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").text();
      var formaTaxa = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").attr('data-taxa');
      var formaTipo = $("#formaPagamento option:selected").attr('data-tipo');
   
      if (formaID == "") {
         var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val("0.00");
      } else {
         var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val(formaTaxa + formaTipo);
      }
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
Forma de pagamento:
<select id="formaPagamento" name="formaPagamento" required>
  <option value="" selected></option>
  <option value="1" data-taxa="3.50" data-tipo="">Boleto</option>
  <option value="2" data-taxa="3.50" data-tipo="%">Cartão credito</option>
  <option value="3" data-taxa="1.50" data-tipo="%">Cartão debito</option>
  <option value="4" data-taxa="0.00" data-tipo="">Dinheiro</option>
</select>

Taxa: 
<input id="formaTaxas" name="formaTaxas" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="0,00" required/>
```

Comment: Olá Sam, ele esta me forçando a usar a %. Mesmo usando uma forma que usa %, se eu quiser colocar um valor sem %, o campo deve permitir, o contrario também seria valido. O campo taxa seria livre para usar com ou sem %. **OBS:** Editei meu post, pois esqueci de colocar o script que formata o input.

Comment: Então é só trocar o evento `input` por `keyup`. E pode remover o replace tb que não será necessário. Fica assim o código: `$('#formaTaxas').bind('keyup', function() {
      $("#formaPagamento option:selected").attr("data-taxa", this.value);
   });`

Comment: O Simblo de % não sai quando tem, ou não deixa colocar quando não tem.

Comment: O maskmoney bloqueia todos os caracteres que não seja número.